# Почему flask_socketio.disconnect препятствует завершению потока?

Tags: python, flask, socketio

Есть следующая система: **[Клиент] - [Веб-сервер] - [Коннектор]**.

Коннектор - это своего рода промежуточный код между веб-сервером и источником данных.

Мне нужно контролировать соединение сервера с коннектором. Если соединение потеряно, я должен уведомить клиента.

Связь между веб-сервером и коннектором организована с помощью socketio.

Проблема в том, что если коннектор перестает работать, то веб-сервер узнает об этом только через минуту (это в лучшем случае).

Я решил, что сервер должен проверять состояние коннектора каждую секунду.

Когда коннектор подключается к серверу, запускается фоновая задача. Суть задачи: каждую секунду: 1) фиксировать время; 2) сохранить фиксированное время в стеке; 3) отправить эхо-сообщение на соединитель. (см. server.background_thread)

Соединитель принимает эхо-сообщение и метку времени в качестве параметра и отправляет эхо-сообщение на веб-сервер, в качестве параметра он передает полученную метку времени. (см. client.echo)

Веб-сервер получает эхо-сообщение, если отметка времени равна последнему значению в стеке, то это значение удаляется из стека. (см. server.on_echo_connector)

На веб-сервере на каждой итерации проверяется размер стека (см. Server.background_thread). Если оно больше 5, то это означает, что коннектор не отвечал на эхо-сообщение 5 раз, считаем, что коннектор недоступен.

Когда сервер понимает, что коннектор недоступен, необходимо завершить поток, который отправил эхо-сообщения соединителю.

Когда размер стека превышает 5, я выхожу из бесконечного цикла и вызываю `flask_socketio.disconnect (connector_sid, '/ connector')`. После этого вызова ничего не работает (например, `print` и т.д.)

В методе `on_disconnect_connector` (server) вызывается `thread.join()` и никогда не завершается.

Нужно завершить поток, чтобы при повторном запуске коннектора он успешно подключился, и все началось заново.

Как решить эту проблему?

Сервер

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import threading
import time
import collections
from datetime import datetime

import flask
import flask_socketio

def get_unix_time():
    return int(time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple()))

class Stack(collections.deque):

    def __init__(self, iterable=(), maxlen=None):
        collections.deque.__init__(self, iterable, maxlen)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self)

    @property
    def empty(self):
        return self.size == 0

    @property
    def head(self):
        return self[-1]

    @property
    def tail(self):
        return self[0]

    def push(self, x):
        self.append(x)

# SERVER

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
sio = flask_socketio.SocketIO(app, async_mode='gevent')

connector_sid = None
echo_stack = Stack()

thread = None
thread_lock = threading.Lock()


def background_thread(app):
    time.sleep(2)  # delay for normal connection

    while True:
        if echo_stack.size >= 5:
            break
        time_ = get_unix_time()
        echo_stack.push(time_)
        sio.emit('echo', time_, namespace='/connector')
        sio.sleep(1)

    with app.app_context():
        flask_socketio.disconnect(connector_sid, '/connector')


@sio.on('connect', namespace='/connector')
def on_connect_connector():
    """Connector connection event handler."""
    global connector_sid, thread
    print 'Attempt to connect a connector {}...'.format(request.sid)

    # if the connector is already connected, reject the connection
    if connector_sid is not None:
        print 'Connection for connector {} rejected'.format(request.sid)
        return False
        # raise flask_socketio.ConnectionRefusedError('Connector already connected')

    connector_sid = request.sid
    print('Connector {} connected'.format(request.sid))

    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = sio.start_background_task(
                background_thread, current_app._get_current_object())

    # уведомить клиента, что коннектор подключен
    sio.emit('set_connector_status', True, namespace='/client')


@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/connector')
def on_disconnect_connector():
    """Connector disconnect event handler."""
    global connector_sid, thread

    print 'start join'
    thread.join()
    print 'end join'
    thread = None
    print 'after disconet:', thread

    connector_sid = None

    echo_stack.clear()

    print('Connector {} disconnect'.format(request.sid))

    # уведомить клиент, что коннектор отключен
    sio.emit('set_connector_status', False, namespace='/client')


@sio.on('echo', namespace='/connector')
def on_echo_connector(time_):
    if not echo_stack.empty:
        if echo_stack.head == time_:
            echo_stack.pop()


@sio.on('message', namespace='/connector')
def on_message_connector(cnt):
    # print 'Msg: {}'.format(cnt)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app)
```

Клиент

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import threading
import time

import socketio
import socketio.exceptions

sio = socketio.Client()
thread = None
thread_lock = threading.Lock()
work = False


def background_thread():
    # example task
    cnt = 0
    while work:
        cnt += 1
        if cnt % 10 == 0:
            sio.emit('message', cnt // 10, namespace='/connector')
        sio.sleep(0.1)


@sio.on('connect', namespace='/connector')
def on_connect():
    """Обработчик события подключенеия к серверу."""
    global thread, work

    print '\n-----            Connected to server            -----' \
          '\n----- My SID:  {} -----\n'.format(sio.sid)

    work = True  # установить флаг работы

    # запустить в потоке цикл опроса Пирамиды
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = sio.start_background_task(background_thread)


@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/connector')
def on_disconnect():
    """Обработчик события отключения от сервера."""
    global thread, work

    # сбросить флаг работы, чтобы на след. итерации беск. цикл завершился
    work = False
    thread.join()
    thread = None

    # отключиться от сервера
    sio.disconnect()
    print '\n-----         Disconnected from server          -----\n'

    # перейти в режим бексонечных попыток подключения к серверу
    main()


@sio.on('echo', namespace='/connector')
def on_echo(time_):
    sio.emit('echo', time_, namespace='/connector')


def main():
    while True:
        try:
            sio.connect('http://localhost:5000/connector',
                        namespaces=['/connector'])
            sio.wait()
        except socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print 'Trying to connect to the server...'
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print '\n---------- EXIT ---------\n'
            sys.exit()
        except Exception as e:
            print e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print '\n---------- START CLIENT ----------\n'
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема долгого ожидания сервером сообщения о том, что коннектор был отключен, заключается в том, что клиент использует в качестве транспорта `polling`. socketio выполняет автоматический переход на транспорт `websocket`, если это возможно, а возможно это тогда, и только тогда, когда установлена библиотека **websocket-client**.

```
pip install "python-socketio[client]"
```

или

```
pip install websocket-client
```

Благодаря данной библиотеке, транспорт меняется на `websocket` (либо можно сразу указать его в параметрах подключения для клиента). А с `websocket` информирование сервера о том, что коннектор был отключен, происходит практически мгновенно.

[Источник](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/254#issuecomment-465882385)